# How to use a specific controller\action on "onchange" for Select_tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im knew on MVC and on Ruby on rail environment 
I have this code
`<%= select :language, :language_id,
        options_for_select([ "Arabic", "English"]),
        {:prompt => "#{t('language')}"},
        {:onChange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'ConfigurationController',:action => "change_language"}
        )}"} %>`
And I cant make the Select to call this action and make PostBack for the page on on change

after selected index change nothing is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? It looks like remote_function was depracated in 3.1 http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function

Use jQuery to respond to the change event:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#select_id").change ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "url",
      dataType: "json",
      data: "data to send")
        .done (data) ->
          do_something_on_success()
        .fail (data) ->
          do_something_on_fail()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a remote function call. can you see in browser's console if there are any errors returned from server.

the syntax of select_tag, you are using looks fine.

Edit:

did u try alerting some thing onchange event? refer this syntax

```
 <%= select_tag "language", options_from_collection_for_select(@collection,'value','name'), html_options = { :onChange=> "alert('');" :style=> "display:block;" } %>
```

where u can create your collection using,

```
@collection = ["en","ab"]
@collection = @collection.map { |name, value| OpenStruct.new(:value => name, :name => name) }
```

Comment: so then what is the problem exactly?

Comment: the page dosn't do postback or any event when I change the selected index

Comment: Then what exactly went wrong? The remote_function helper doesn't expect anything back from the server. It just sends a request.

Comment: at least it should do a post back , and see the page refresh ... right?

Comment: It should not refresh the page.  You can tell if it posted back to the server from the log.  If you use the alert as suggested, does the alert appear?